# Override Properties for JUnit with Properties File

Tags: apache-camel

I have got my properties defined using JNDI Entries on the server rather than an application properties file. This caused issues with my JUnits as they don't access the server. In my JUnit I used the method useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent to add a list of properties which has resolved my issue. I'd rather add a file test.properties and list my properties in here instead. Can this be done using this or a similar method?

Comment: You can just load the properties from the file in that method. There is an API on Properties itself to load from file AFAIR.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way of doing it but I took a slightly different approach `@Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = super.createCamelContext();
        context.addComponent("properties", new PropertiesComponent("file:src/test/resources/application.properties"));
        return context;
    }`